# Separate layout of ContentPage to multiple ContentViews

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I was experimenting with NET MAUI and got to the point where my layout of HomePage became too long, so I would like to split layout to several controls. I have registered ViewModel as Interface using Dependency Injection.

The problem is that currently it looks like my HomeViewModel is not passed to MyControl as I am seeing any content specified in MyControl in my HomePage. I would like to pass HomeViewModel from HomePage to MyControl. How it should be done correctly?

HomePage.xaml.cs:

```
public HomePage(IHomeViewModel homeViewModel)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = homeViewModel;
    this.HomeViewModel = homeViewModel;
}
```

HomePage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.HomePage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyApp.Controls;assembly=MyApp"
             x:DataType="viewModels:HomeViewModel"
             Title="">

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <controls:MyControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BindingContext="{Binding}" />

  </Grid>


</ContentPage>
```

MyControl.xaml:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
             x:DataType="viewModels:HomeViewModel"
             xmlns:models="clr-namespace:MyApp.Models"
             x:Name="this"
             x:Class="MyApp.Controls.MyControl">

  <ContentView.BindingContext>
    <x:Reference Name="this" />
  </ContentView.BindingContext>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Frame Opacity="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding ThemeColor}">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Label Text="Title" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
          <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:DataModel">
                <ViewCell>
                  <Grid Padding="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Subject}"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Number}"/>
                  </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </Grid>
      </Frame>
  </Grid>

</ContentView>
```

HomeViewModel.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<DataModel> data;
public ObservableCollection<DataModel> Data
{
  get => this.data;
  set
  {
    this.data = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

DataModel.cs:

```
  public class DataModel
  {
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:

```xml
<ContentView.BindingContext>
    <x:Reference Name="this" />
</ContentView.BindingContext>
```

Then it will inherit BindingContext from its parent (containing element), which is the page.

---

**Correct Initialization of Data**

All `DataModel` instances must set their `Subject` and `Number` BEFORE they are made visible to XAML.

REASON: `DataModel` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on its properties; property changes are NOT automatically "recursive".

3 possible ways to fix:

---

FIX #1:

```cs
// Prepare all data BEFORE setting `Data`:
var data = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
foreach (...)
{
    var model = new DataModel();

    // Can set Subject and Number here.
    model.Subject = ...;
    model.Number = ...;

    // Because model is not yet visible in `Data`, we can do `data.Add`
    // EITHER before or after setting `Subject` and/or `Number`.
    data.Add(model);

    // Or set them here.
    model.Subject = ...;
    model.Number = ...;
}
// When all data is fully prepared:
Data = data;   // Now XAML sees the prepared data.
```

---

OR FIX #2:

```cs
// Prepare each model BEFORE adding it to `Data`:
Data = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>();
foreach (...)
{
    var model = new DataModel(){ Subject = ..., Number = ... };
    // IMPORTANT: Subject and Number MUST be set BEFORE `Data.Add(model)`!
    Data.Add(model);
}
// When all data is fully prepared:
Data = data;   // Now XAML sees the prepared data.
```

---

OR FIX #3:

```cs
class DataModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]   // Compiler generates public property "Subject", with property change notification.
    private string subject;
    [ObservableProperty]   // Compiler generate "Number" ...
    private string number;
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I have somehow got it partly working. I can see that for example ThemeColor of Frame is functioning correctly and is getting value from HomeViewModel, but then LisView is empty and is not displaying items from ObservableCollection Data on HomeViewModel.
P.S. Actually there are items in ListView. I don't see Subject and Number for some reason.

Comment: So now everything is working, except that ListView DataTemplate, as it is not able to display specified properties. I see just empty lines in ListView.

Comment: Add to question: 1) Declaration of `Data`, and which class that is in. Something like `public class HomeViewModel { public ObservableCollection<??> Data { get; set; }`. Whatever your exact details are, need to see them added to question. 2) Declarations of `Subject` and `Number`, and which class they are in.

Comment: I have added missing classes to my question

Comment: 1) `class HomeViewModel`: Is the declaration line `class HomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged`? Or does it inherit from a class that has `: INotifyPropertyChanged`? This is needed, for XAML to recognize `OnPropertyChanged` as being part of INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: DataModel does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged. See new section of answer "Correct Initialization of Data".

Comment: I some some time on finding an issue. My problem was that I was actually having Converter that I have not specified while moving ListView's to MyControl.xaml